# Comma separator in aChartEngine

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine, separator

I'm using aChartEngine to design charts for my app reports but i wanted to know that is it possible to have a comma separator for XYSeries in BarCharts?

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: dear Dan my question is that my bar charts are charts related to product sales , so their amount is huge and chart's value without separator is not well readble.i wanted to know that is there any way to make my chart's value separated like ###,###,###

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the answer with the help of dear Dan and i want to share this with you maybe it's someone else issue,hope it helps:

After updating my achartengine jar file to build 1.1.0 , i've found a handy function named 'setChartValuesFormat' in XYSeriesRenderer , so i've defined a NumberFormat like below :

```
public static final NumberFormat IntegerFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.##");
```

then i used this NumberFormat in that function :

```
SalesRenderer.setChartValuesFormat(GlobalVariables.IntegerFormatter);
```

and it works Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use annotations instead of regular chart values.

```
series.addAnnotation("Vacation", 6, 30);
```

You must download a recent version of the library. For example, get the night build from [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/).

Comment: Thank you Dan for your Answer(+1 for helping me out ;)) after i've updated to new build i've solved the issue with function : setChartValuesFormat,i had answered my question myself maybe it may help someone else.Good Luck